# Webflux combine two Monos with dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor

I want to create a Spring-Webflux-Service that combines the data of two sources with a dependency. I'm new to Webflux so I have no idea how to do that. Here is some pseudo code to shows what I`m trying to do:

```java
@Service
public class ServiceB {

    private RepositoryB repositoryB;
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    public Mono<BigDecimal> calculate(UUID id) {
        return repositoryB.findById(id)
                .flatMap(b -> serviceA.find(b.getId()))
                .flatMap((a, b) -> a + b);

    }
```

The result of `repositoryB` includes the identifier of the data I want to find with `serviceA`. At least I want to work on both datasets. What method could I use instead of the first `flatMap`?

Comment: `flatMap` looks fine. What’s the issue?

Comment: The second `flatMap` is the issue. I can't define the tuple (a, b) as input. The code in my question doesn't compile.

Comment: @mifloma I think you need a map there, are RepositoryB and ServiceA returning Mono?

Comment: @LiviuStirb Yes, both return a Mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use [`Mono.zipWhen`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#zipWhen-java.util.function.Function-), to zip the two `Monos` into a `Tuple`:

```
public Mono<BigDecimal> calculate(UUID id) {
    return repositoryB.findById(id)
            .zipWhen(b -> serviceA.find(b.getId())
            .map(t -> t.getT1().add(t.getT2()));
}
```

Also, please note, you can not add two `BigDecimals` with `+`.